# how to translate MTB wheel specifications?

Tags: mountain-bike, wheels

I am looking for a pair of wheels for a MTB build project, but I am lost when I read the specifications for wheel sets.

What I am looking for is a pair of wheels with a 9mm rear axle diameter and a 15mm front axle diameter.

But how do I know if a pair with quick releases will fit when it says nothing about the axle diameter?

Example "Available with 9mm or 15mm front axle" so? What is the rear axle diameter?

I am not asking what kind of wheelsmyou like or which you think I should and shouldn't buy. I need help understanding the specifications from the manufacures.

Comment: I think it would be useful to post a wheel or two which you are considering to give a concrete example of specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rear wheels have never had 9mm axles, they have always been 10mm. For all but "downhill" MTB[2] and fatbikes[3], they are  either 135mm 10mm or the new 12mm 142mm maxle standard.

http://www.pinkbike.com/news/12x142-explained.html

Unless it specifically states otherwise I would assume that the rear wheel of an MTB wheelset is a 135mm 10mm axle. Anything that "looks" like a standard QR should be 135mm 10mm. But the vendor should make that pretty obvious, and if they don't it should be easy to ask. Wheelsets are expensive, it should be simple to get the answer to what dimensions are used in the rear hub.

[2]- Downhill MTB has a 150mm thru-axle standard.

[3]- Fatbikes use asymmetric 135mm axles (hub shifted to the driveside, relative to the rim) 170mm symmetric axles and 190mm/197mm thru-axles

Comment: good link, good site, +1

Comment: Aaand we have [148mm](http://www.pinkbike.com/news/trek-remedy-29-carbon-penske-first-look.html) rear length.

Comment: AAARGH, why would Trek not just use 150mm???

Answer (score 0):

There are a large number of standards when it comes to just axle diameter.
largest to smallest, with usual usage:-

20mm - This is used as a front wheel downhill/freeride standard.

15mm - This is front wheel standard for XC

12mm - This is used in rear wheel thru axle

10mm - This is front or rear bolt-through standard

9mm - This is front or rear quick release standard.

This then gets even more confusing when you look at axle length. However for both of the standards you are after, unless the frame is very old, have standard axle lengths. If you are really worried about getting the right/wrong wheels, some hubs have interchangeable axles. For instance Hope Tech.

Comment: In the higher profile, mid - high end, 15mm XC is common, but its hardly "standard" - a majority of bikes sold are at the cheaper end and still have 9mm QR's.

Comment: 10mm QR not used on front

Comment: Thanks,the inner distance between my rear dropouts is 135mm the frame is from 2006. So I should safely assume rear hub is 9mm unless anything specific is stated

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? IMHO this is the best answer to the question so far, the other one recommending to 'assume' things.

Comment: @Vorac because it is inaccurate and lacks information that would make it a complete answer. Widths and diameters should be answered together, not said it is confusing.

Comment: @DWGKNZ, but it *is* confusing. Things should get measured and specifically checked, not 'assumed'. Heck, I purchased a complete groupset and the FD didn't fit the build!

Comment: Your rear hub is 10mm not 9.

Comment: @DWGKNZ 10mm is not used as a QR standard at all. This is a bolt-up/bolt-through standard. And to the fact is it not used on the front, I have a bike hanging on the wall behind me that would disagree. To your later point on how width  and diameter should be put together, that's all well and good to say but in practice doesn't work. The original post referred to diameter and not width, thus I endeavored to avoid adding complication.

Comment: @Henry - Current MTB standard QR hubs are 9mmx100mm front and 10mmx135mm rear. Yes bolt-throughs are also 10mm. 10mm front axles have been made, but they aren't standard or are old (Shimano used them 30-40 years ago).

Comment: @Henry - Are you possibly meaning 3/8 BMX hubs? I think some people call them 10mm also....